# Passing Datacontext as CommandParameter to Viewmodel in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, command, windows-10

I am displaying the data in the gridview in a grouped style. I am already can create new items. Now I want to create a function that can delete the item that I create. Here is my viewmodel :

## Viewmodel

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VM()
    {
        DeleteItem = new DelegateCommand(DeleteCurrentItem);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Contact> ContList = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

    private ObservableCollection<Category> _GroupedCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Category> GroupedCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_GroupedCollection == null)
                _GroupedCollection = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
            return _GroupedCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _GroupedCollection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GroupedCollection"));
        }
    }

    public void DeleteCurrentItem(object param)
    {
        var cont= param as Contact;
        // there is another class that declare another ObservableCollection that holds all the models.
        var category = GroupedCollection.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == cont.Account);
        if (category != null)
        {
            if (category.CredCategory.Contains(cont))
            {
                category.CredCategory.Remove(cont);
            }
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand DeleteItem { get; set; }

    private string _Account;
    public string Account
    {
        get { return _Account; }
        set
        {
            _Account = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Account"));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In my XAML, I have a flyout, which work as desired. I can hold the data displayed and the flyout will appear/open. But when I click "Delete", the 'gridview' does not delete it.

## View (XAML)

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <data:VM/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True" 
                          Source="{Binding GroupedCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          ItemsPath="CredCategory"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
   <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
       <MenuFlyout x:Name="flyout">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItem, ElementName=gridview}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
   </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
   <GridView x:Name="gridview" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                 .  .  .  .
                <DataTemplate/>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView/>
<Grid/>
```

I am showing the code-behind in case someone wants to see it.

## View (Code-Behind)

```
public void cardstack_pass_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this is the event declared in the Datatemplate inside gridview
        flyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

As I stated at the above, my problem is when I click the "Delete" on `flyout`, it should be deleting the data from the `ObservableCollection` right? Because as far as I know, the DataContext of the `flyout` is the DataContext of the data displayed, or am I wrong? How to fix this?

I mean, the `gridview`'s DataContext is the ObservableCollection, and the Stackpanels' DataContext inside `gridview`'s DataTemplate will be the Model `Contact` right? Since `flyout` was open at the item created, so the DataContext of `flyout` will inherit from the item's DataContext, and if the `flyout`'s `CommandParameter = "{Binding}"`, it should pass the `Contact` inside the item to the viewmodel, isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside `DeleteCurrentItem` and looking at the type of the parameter?

Comment: hi @MikeEason yes, I already have, but the app should be suspended right? But my app just keeps on running. (I am still learning)

Comment: @rydev No, your breakpoint will be hit just before that particular line is about to be executed. If it's not, it means that the delete method is never being called

Comment: Well. If your breakpoint isn't being hit, then the method isn't being called. Check the output window for binding errors, perhaps the binding is wrong?

Comment: thanks for the knowledge! Already tried the answer's method and turns out the placement of my FlyoutBase is wrong, thank you for your time tho  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something here but shouldn't the `AttachedFlyout` code go in the `DataTemplate`

Note Binding of Command to element name root (Page name) as we're inside the GridView  eg

```
<Page x:Name="root">
    <Page.DataContext>
      <data:VM/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Page.Resources>
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True" 
                      Source="{Binding GroupedCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsPath="CredCategory"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
      <GridView x:Name="gridview" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
          <GridView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                   <MenuFlyout x:Name="flyout">
                      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" 
                           Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItem, ElementName=root}" 
                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                 </MenuFlyout>
              </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>                 
            <DataTemplate/>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
     <GridView/>
  <Grid/>
```

This [article](http://igrali.com/2014/04/28/show-context-menu-using-menuflyout-windows-phone-8-1/) shows how to use `Behaviours` which are available in UWP.

Comment: thank you @Swilko! tried your method, and it worked as desired! and I thought the problem is the `CommandParameter`.. haha thanks again ^_^

Comment: Excellent glad it helped :)